# ubuntu 22.04 add -Y to SSH

Tags: 22.04, ssh, xorg

Just starting to use a Ubuntu 22.04 desktop (call it HOME) and connecting to another Linux host (call it AWAY) to run Xwindows applications.

From HOME, I want to run an XWindows app on AWAY like geany so on HOME, after I SSH to AWAY, I can run:

```
user@AWAY: $ geany &
```

This just worked when I used MobaXTerm on Windows 10 because it has a built in X server but on Ubuntu I get the

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Geany: cannot open display
```

I found I can do this with

```
user@HOME: $ ssh -Y AWAY
```

Which sets things up properly, but I have other machines and other users that will want to connect and run apps on AWAY. This is a trusted LAN, so I'm OK with -Y as default but can't figure out how to make it the default.

I looked at the options for config in .ssh and don't see how to make -Y automatic so remote hosts can run X apps from AWAY without sharing some kind of batch scripts or alias file.

Note that I'm probably searching ineffectively: *"run X application on ubuntu 22.04 from remote host"* always turns up tips on how to serve X apps as if I were running them from HOME, but I want to run them on HOME from AWAY.

Is there language I should use when searching for help that would get better results for my situation of

```
[HOME] 
   (wants to run an X app hosted on)
[AWAY]
```

so 2 questions.

1. Default -Y SSH connections to AWAY from hosts on my trusted LAN.
2. Better search terminology for looking for help setting up X applications.

Comment: As far as the `Default -Y SSH` I would recommend using `-X` instead where you can put a line in your `~/.ssh/config` file that states `ForwardX11 yes` that way you don't need to use `-Y` or `-X` on your connection.  As far as your second question goes, a X application is usually any app that runs in the GUI and I don't think that there is a good search for one.

Comment: Although not related to this question, I find X very slow for remote Linux-to-Linux connections. Instead, I prefer RDP.

Comment: Terrance - thanks! Is that in the client (HOME) ssh/config or AWAY's sshd_config?

FedKad - that would certainly work, but I'd rather not use RDP and mess with installing an RDP client, etc as clients don't need AWAY's entire desktop, just a couple of applications.

Comment: That would be on the client side.  But, it can cause X11 Forwarding messages to appear.  But they are just warnings.